# Execute a queue of Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I need to execute a queue of thread. I need that only one thread is in execution and then put other thread in a queue and when the current thread is completed I need to pass to the first in the queue.

I need that to implement live search on my JTable. The table holds 50.000 rows so without this method the performance are really bad. I' ve no idea how to implement it. Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: it is a challenging task, but are you very sure need the queue of the threads and with Thread creation and memory allocation overhead, especially if only 1 is running? I think you need a que of interfaces and just switch the objects, not threads.

Comment: Are you going to start 50000 threads and then allow them to execute one at a time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a single-threaded [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) from [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29). You can pass your jobs as `Runnable` objects to the `Executor` and let it do the work for you.

```
private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void doSomethingWith(final Object obj) {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // Do something with obj
        }
    });
}
```

Put the code you want to run once-at-a-time in the `run` method.

Comment: @Nambari From the docs: "Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time."

Answer (score 0):

`SingleThreadExecutor` from `java.util.concurrency` is the answer to your question...

**-** It has a Thread size of one....

**-** Complete **1st task first before moving to 2nd,**

**-** It maintains its **own hidden queue** to keep the track of the task remaining with it...

Comment: But it doesnt guarantee thread order, is it? Could you provide any reference for "Own hidden queue" statement?

Comment: @Nambari...i don't think there is a way to determine the thread order...it all depends on JVM thread Scheduler, further JVM thread Scheduler behave differently on different OS... `But the task here in this case will execute in the way it has been submitted.....`  `cause thats what SingleThreadExecutor does.....maintains a Queue`